# How can I sort my array without repeating element

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

how can I write the objects in my array to the console without repeating them. Have one of each element in the array. For example this --

```js
   const arr = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Jake'
        },
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Jake'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Sara'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Sara'
        }
    ]
    
    
       const newArray = [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Jake'
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Sara'
        }
    ]
```

```js
const otherArray = [12, 23, 25, 12, 25, 46]
const newOtherArray = [12, 23, 25, 45]
```